Can I continue using technology after it is patented
Let’s say I use a very specific software communication technique applied in a novel way that could be patented. I don’t patent this invention because I am a startup that has little money to invest in an unproven application.
A few months/years later a large company independently patents this invention.
Can I continue using this invention ("practicing the patent" in patent terminology) without risk of successfully being sued?
We can assume there’s proof I was using this invention prior to the patent.
Does this change depending on whether big company had knowledge of our usage at time of filing the patent?

@RussellMcMahon Patent applications are confidential until publication, 18 months from earliest filing date. That is a window where somebody can independently re-invent and they wouldn't know.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There is a prior commercial use defence to patent infringement.
Further, if the invention was previously disclosed publicly ("prior art"), then one could even object to the issuance of the patent.

Could the prior originator assume the issued patent and proceed to commercially exploit it? (or does the patent lapse)

@civitas certainly not without paying the patent fees, which is why they neglected to file it in the fist place

FYI, I was working at Microsoft in the early 1990's on an internal program that received US patent data updates, converted it to an appropriate format, updated a database, and then allowed searching/display of various parts of the data. Our manager told us that IBM quite often had new ideas, but didn't think they were worthwhile to patent, so they instead published the appropriate details in their IBM Systems Journal. This was to try to prevent other companies from patenting them instead by making it be "prior art".

@JohnOmielan: As an ex-IBMer I can confirm that "publish" was one of the explicit responses to an invention disclosure, for just that reason.

"Can I continue using this invention"
Yes you can, if you do indeed have proof of prior art/prior use.
"Can I continue ... without risk of  being sued?"
No. There is a significant risk that the other party will sue - they (probably) wouldn't have paid for the patent in the first place if they didn't intend to 'defend it'.
"Can I continue ... without risk of successfully being sued?"
How much money do you have to pay for a good lawyer? If your answer is 'none' then I'm afraid the risk is again significant. If you've got a good lawyer, then the risk is a lot lower, but never quite zero.

At least in Switzerland, but AFAIK also in the US, you can not even claim a patent for work that is prior art. The patent office is obliged to check. At least that is what Albert Einstein did for a living during his time in Bern: https://www.ige.ch/en/about-us/the-history-of-the-ipi/einstein/einstein-at-the-patent-office

@Marcel  It is fairly widely reported that most/all patent offices lack the resources to do the necessary due diligence any more. Prior art is therefore mostly only relevant in court. The basic premise of the OP's question was that prior art existed, AND that a conflicting patent had been granted.

lawfare vs rule of law

@Marcel, you can file a patent application for virtually anything.  The chances of it being granted are less if there is prior art, but how much less varies widely.  If BigCorp and I independently invent the same thing, but I don't disclose the invention, then it seems unlikely that that would lead a patent examiner to reject BigCorp's patent application because of prior art.  If BigCorp is granted that  patent then they absolutely can set about enforcing it.

Moreover, the U.S. presently has a first-to-file patent system, so even if I invented the thing years before BigCorp did, that's not in itself a basis to reject or invalidate BigCorp's (U.S.) patent.

@JohnBollinger, well - if you have indisputable evidence that you did invent the thing before the patent - such as a published article, paper, GitHub repository, clear photographs, timestamped sealed envelope containing invention details (was the cheap version in the old days), timestamped signature of public attorney, etc - then you have prior art.

@Konchog: Only some of those count as "prior art" (which excludes trade secrets).  See the other answer for the distinction between that and "prior commercial use" (which can be as a trade secret).

@Konchog, "prior art" doesn't mean "someone else already knew about it."  It means something closer to "a typical competent practitioner in the field could be expected to have known about it."

@JohnBollinger, well now, that depends upon jurisdiction.  As we know, US Patents tend to be handed out more freely than in Europe, which has caused issue via the Patent Cooperation Treaty.  The EPO states: "Prior art does not need to exist physically or be commercially available. It is enough that someone, somewhere, sometime previously has described or shown or made something that contains a use of technology that is very similar to your invention." You may dispute me, but my position is valid under EU patent law.  I should have qualified jurisdiction, but your rebuttal needed same.

@JohnBollinger  "Prior Art" does indeed mean "at least one other person knew about it". You seem to be thinking of "Obviousness", though essentially that is just a sub-category of "Prior Art". As I understand it, "First to file" merely means that the second person to file, cannot obtain a patent, even if they can prove that they thought of it first - it says nothing direct about invalidity.
